# Статус sms-сообщения

Tags: java, android, sms, android-broadcastreceiver, pendingintent

Никак не получается запросить статусы смс-сообщений - приложение вылетает.

Объясните неофиту в чем может быть причина.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //объекты
    private EditText editText_for_sms;
    private Button button;

    String SENT_SMS="SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED_SMS="SMS_DELIVERED";

    Intent sent_intent = new Intent(SENT_SMS);
    Intent deliver_intent = new Intent(DELIVERED_SMS);

    PendingIntent sentPI;
    PendingIntent deliveredPI;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,
                sent_intent,0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,
                deliver_intent,0);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        EditText editText_for_sms = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_for_sms);       
    }


    //Обработчик кнопок
      public void onClickButton(View view) {                      
            //Переключатель между кнопками:
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.button:
                    //MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
                    //myTask.execute();

                    //блок с нажатием
                    //для вывода на экран
                    MyTask myTask = new MyTask();

                    String my_http = null;
                    try {
                        myTask.execute();
                        my_http = myTask.get();
                        String[] ttt = my_http.split("<message");
                        String[][] broken_input_m = new String[ttt.length][4];
                        int i;
                        String[] tmp_arr_1_m;
                        for (i = 1; i < ttt.length; i++){
                            String[] tmp_arr_m = ttt[i].split(">");
                            tmp_arr_1_m = tmp_arr_m[0].split("\"");
                            String[] tmp_arr_2_m = tmp_arr_m[1].split("<");
                            broken_input_m[i-1][0]=tmp_arr_1_m[1];
                            broken_input_m[i-1][1]=tmp_arr_1_m[3];
                            broken_input_m[i-1][2]=tmp_arr_1_m[5];
                            broken_input_m[i-1][3]=tmp_arr_2_m[0];
                        }
                        /*for(i = 0; i < broken_input_m.length; i++){*/

                        SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(broken_input_m[i][0], null, broken_input_m[i][3],
                                sentPI, deliveredPI);
                            /*if (i == 2)
                                break;*/


                        EditText editText_for_sms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_for_sms);
                        editText_for_sms.setText(my_http);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, vivod_na_ekran.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }



    //Данный метод нужен для запуска различных объектов
    //например, широковещательных приемников или
    //для инициализации компонентов
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(sentReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT_SMS));
        registerReceiver(deliverReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED_SMS));
    }



    //Данный метод служит для остановки
    //BroadcastReceiver'ов - широковещательных сообщений
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(sentReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(deliverReceiver);
    }



    //Обработка отправления смс:
    //выводим оповещение с информацией об отправки
    //сообщения
    BroadcastReceiver sentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (getResultCode()){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Сообщение выслано", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Cообщение не выслано", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };



    //Обработка доставки смс:
    //выводим оповещение с информацией о доставки
    //сообщения
    BroadcastReceiver deliverReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (getResultCode()){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Сообщение отправлено", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Сообщение не отправлено", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };



    //Создаем MyTask для http запрос
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private String http_request;

        //метод с запросом к http странице
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
                ResponseHandler response = new BasicResponseHandler();
                HttpGet http = new HttpGet("тут находится пхп с данными");
                http_request = (String) hc.execute(http, response);               

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return http_request;
        }

        //место для метода onPostExecute
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            result = http_request;           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите стек-трейс.

Comment: @post_zeew
вот, держите.
https://pastebin.com/tZSHhWig

Comment: Вы стек-трейс отфильтруйте хотя бы по Вашему приложению.

Comment: @post_zeww извиняюсь, вот вроде все правильно сделал https://pastebin.com/RTH9J3bX 
p.s. и на будущее: нормально ли заливать различные стак-трейсы/логи и прочие большие объемы информации на пейстбин? или лучше что-то другое использовать?

Comment: Покажите 143 строку из файла `MainActivity.java`. Всю информацию лучше заливать прямо в текст вопроса, ибо сторонние хостинги сегодня есть, а завтра – нет (я сейчас не про pastebin, а в общем).

Comment: @post_zeew понял вас, вот код со 143 строки 
`SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(broken_input_m[i][0], null, broken_input_m[i][3],sentPI, deliveredPI);` ,данная строка принадлежит методу onClickButton, который в вопросе есть.

Comment: Вы вылетаете за пределы массива: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3`.

Comment: @post_zeew проблему с вылетом из массива я исправил, теперь стек-трейс принял такой вид https://pastebin.com/dfCfrj7F

Comment: Смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по стек-трейсу:

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
```

Вы выходите за пределы массива в строке:

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(broken_input_m[i][0]‌​, null, broken_input_m[i][3],sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

**UPD**. Далее, судя по строке:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10060 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
```

у Вас либо нет разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

в `AndroidManifest.xml`, либо Вы его не запрашиваете в рантайме (а запрашивать нужно, так как это разрешение относится к категории *dangerous*).

Пример с *runtime permissions* из [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

Запрос:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Обработка ответа от пользователя:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```